# Get only rows when column is duplicated and timestamps get a difference between them

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to figured out how get only the rows within duplicated values but differents timestamps. Each timestamp should be between -1/+1 minutes of diff at maximum.

| id | client_id | amount | token | sales_ref_id | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29238 | 6.333 | a$idjqb5AUdnh34 | 380 | 2020-11-17 18:45 |
| 2 | 2008 | 200 | kla3@nans#9aisD | 9 | 2020-11-17 18:45 |
| 3 | 2008 | 200 | 4843$a1s00c4544 | 9 | 2020-11-17 18:46 |
| 4 | 2008 | -200 | va$ie32u*Asc2001 | 9 | 2020-11-17 18:48 |
| 5 | 1800 | 6.333 | a$id4843$0c45c44 | 19 | 2020-11-17 19:44 |

Like the data above, I should get only the rows #2 and #3, because they have the same client, amount, sales_ref_id and only have 1 minutes plus or less of difference.

But I dont have any clue how should I start to a close solution.

Comment: Tag with the correct RDBMS as the date math varies by RDBMS.

Comment: tagged. sorry :)

Comment: Is there a primary key in the table?

Comment: I updated the row to id, because I though would be unecessary

Comment: SQLite provides rowid as an integer primary key even if a primary key is not defined. Anyway check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.id <> t1.id
    AND (t2.client_id, t2.amount, t2.sales_ref_id) = (t1.client_id, t1.amount, t1.sales_ref_id)
    AND ABS(strftime('%s', t2.updated_at) - strftime('%s', t1.updated_at)) <= 60
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3b902d6219fea8ce504370d8d5486830).